# How can we select time between two columns in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone tell me that how I can execute this query in mysql with php? i want to put

```
SELECT * FROM `takeaway_czip` WHERE '10:00PM' BETWEEN '12:00AM' AND '12:00PM;'
SELECT * FROM `takeaway_czip` WHERE '$abc' BETWEEN 'column1' AND 'column2';
```

Please let me know how I can do it? My client says that he inserts opening and closing time from admin PHP and when a user selects the product it must match current time to opening and closing or between?

Comment: what is the time format & style in table , can you provide your structure please

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM takeaway_czip WHERE opening_time<=NOW() and NOW()<=closing_time` where `opening_time` and `closing_time` are columns in the database.